# In Young's doublte slit experiment what happens if instead of cylindrical , spherical wavefront are taken?

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

Specifically in case of wavefront developed similar to wavefront developed by a convex or a concave  lens .(essentially getting converging or diveging beam of light )
Do we see straight strips of dark and light spots or the shape of the strip changes ?
Y

Comment: If you add up the spherical wavefronts coming from every point of the slit, then you essentially get an approximation of a cylindrical wavefront, and the approximation gets better as the slit gets longer.

Comment: Dear Harshit, is it possible, please, to clarify exactly what arrangement you have in mind, as your questions seems ambiguous to me.

Comment: I wanted to block off the rest of the silts so that we are left with essentially two converging beam of light .

Comment: Is the question "What pattern results from doing a two-pinhole experiment?" (how I interpreted it) or "How do I understand the two-slit pattern in terms of spherical Hyugens' wavefronts?" (how @probably_someone seems to have interpreted it)?

Comment: "What pattern results from doing a two pinhole experiment ?" That should be the question. But they will give the same result imo. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Think of two circular aperture diffraction patterns in combination on a screen.